Noun + をして + passive
On volume 7 of かつて神だった獣たちへ I found this sentence:

わずかに残された研究記録にはソニウムをして『神の化石』との表記が見られるが、儀神兵の力を神になぞらえ表したものなのか、あるいは別の意味を持つのかは不明である

As context, ソニウム is a mineral that could be part of the process of creation of 儀神兵{ぎしんへい}, modified soldiers that can take the form and powers of mitological creatures; 神の化石 is something used in the process of creating 儀神兵.
As far as I understand, in the records there is mention of 神の化石, but it's unclear if it refers to something that gives gods-like power to the soldier, or something else; but I'm not sure how to read をして: maybe something like "made using", 神の化石 made using ソニウム?
I found that をして + causative is a classical grammatical form, but I'm not sure what does it mean when used with a passive verb instead.

This をして is not directly paired with 見られる. I think this をして is used as a highly stilted equivalent of について or に対して.

わずかに残された研究記録にはソニウムをして『神の化石』との表記が見られる
In the few remaining research records, with respect to sonium, a notion of "the fossil of Gods" is seen.
→ The few remaining research records have references to sonium as "the fossil of Gods".

While I believe my interpretation of the sentence is correct, I am not sure whether the usage of をして here is "standard". をして is normally paired with a causative form, but in reality, をして is sometimes used somewhat freely, without causation, to impart a sense of dignity. The question you linked discusses another example of this.
Here are similar examples I feel I have seen somewhere before. Please don't ask me if these are really correct.

彼をして不可能だなんて！
≈ 彼にも不可能だなんて！
So it's impossible even for him!
我をしてここまで追い込むとは！
≈ 我をここまで追い込むとは！
I can't believe you pushed me this far!
AをしてBとみなす
to regard A as B

